# Orbits of dihedral group

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

How can I determine orbits of dihedral group $D_n$? Any relevant references will be useful.

I consider cycle graph with $n$ vertices and (as I understand) its automorphism group is $D_n$. Then, consider adjacency matrix of this graph, $A$. I use the following definition of group orbit:
$$\phi(G,i)=\lbrace\pi(i)\mid \pi\in G\rbrace,$$
where $G=\text{Aut}(A)$.

I have virtually zero knowledge in group theory, so my qeustion may be is not clear.

Comment: Acting on itself? Or on the vertices of a regular $n$-gon? Both of those actions are transitive.

Comment: The natural action of $D_n$ on the cycle graph with $n$ vertices is *transitive*: there is only one orbit.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin and how can I represent it? As I understand, I should start with $D_n$ representation but I have no ideas how to 'capture' orbit

Comment: You need to say what the action *is*. The natural action of $D_n$ on the cycle is by rotations and reflections.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin assuming natural action, how should I interprete the orbit of $D_n$?

Comment: First: it's the orbit of the **action** of $D_n$, not of $D_n$ (or the orbit of a vertex of the graph under the action of $D_n$). Second: there is one and only one orbit, and it includes all vertices of the graph. Third: there is nothing to "interpret".